# How do I detect which radio button has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using `Knockout JS` to toggle between two radio buttons. This works and now I'm trying to figure out how I can toggle a css class when I click `yes/no` so I can show / hide the message box.

[image]

It's been a while since I implemented this and I'm new to Knockout. So I have two questions.

1. I see I'm using `data-toggle="buttons-radio"` to bind the buttons using Knockout. But I can't find any code in my js where I toggle the 'active / inactive' class. Should I find anything in my JS?
2. I know I can add `data-bind="click: myFunction"` on each radio input. But since I'm using `data-toggle`, I'm wondering if I can use that. If so, is this a more "correct" way, and how do I do it?

> ```
>  <label for="Store_is_web_store">Is this a web store?</label>
>  <div class="button-group binary" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
>      <span class="radio-wrapper">
>          <input type="radio" class="active" name="is_web_store" value="1" />
>          <span class="background">Yes</span>
>      </span>
>
>      <span class="radio-wrapper">
>          <input type="radio" class="inactive" name="is_web_store" value="0" checked="checked" />
>          <span class="background">No</span>
>      </span>
>  </div>
>
>  <div class="slide-in-out-container">
>      <div class="message-box">
>          <div class="message-text">
>              Msg here
>          </div>
>      </div>
>  </div>
> ```

This is the only JS code that I use for this page:

```
function registerStoreModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.brands = ko.observableArray();
    self.brand_name = ko.observable();
    self.brand_id = ko.observable();

    // Add brand
    self.addBrand = function() {

        if (self.brand_name() != "") {
            // Add brand to GUI list
            self.brands.push(new brand(self.brand_id(), self.brand_name()));
            self.brand_name("");
        }
    }.bind(self);

    // Remove brand
    self.removeBrand = function(brand) {
        self.brands.remove(brand);
    }

}
```

Comment: Mind posting your model/knockoutjs code?

Comment: Something to try when you have JS questions is to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the relevant HTML/CSS/JS and post a link to it in your question. It makes it a lot easier for people to see your code in action and debug things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your JavaScript it's hard to give you an exact answer however assuming you have an observable on your view model called isWebstore, I believe the following should set you on your way.

```
<div class="button-group binary" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" class="active" name="is_web_store" value="1" data-bind="checked: isWebstore" />
        <span class="background">Yes</span>
    </span>
    <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" class="inactive" name="is_web_store" value="0" data-bind="checked: isWebstore" />
        <span class="background">No</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: isWebstore() === '1'" class="slide-in-out-container">
    <div class="message-box">
        <div class="message-text">
            Msg here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a very basic example of it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmtj5eo2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **computed observable** (docs [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html))

It's similar to the other answer, but a little cleaner imo.

**Javascript**

```
this.showMessage = ko.computed(function() {
    return isWebstore() === '1';
}, this);
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="visible: showMessage()" class="slide-in-out-container">
    <div class="message-box">
        <div class="message-text">
            Msg here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22p5fm19/3/)